# Inline angular template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I've been trying to make a small website that has a main page where a part is changed using templates. I've made an HTML file that contains a small menu for choosing what to show and two templates. If i use the google CDN it works without any problems but i would like to use a local version of angular but that breaks my site and the routing doens't work. The HTML and JS file can be seen below.
Can anyone see what i'm missing?

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-csp="">

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>Test app</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-callout.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css">

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script> -->
   <script src="angular/angular-1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="angular/angular-1.6.1/angular-route.js"></script>
   <script src="js/app.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="backgroundColor">
   <div class="divHeader">
      <div class="center-header">
         <div class="container" style="">
            <a ng-href="#/">
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div>
      <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
         <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/Page1">Page 1</a></li>
         <li><a ng-href="#/">Home</a></li>
         <li class="icon">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="resizeMenu()">&#9776;</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="edge edge-shadow"></div>

   <script type="text/ng-template" id="main.html">
      <div class="panel-group">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Home</div>
            <div class="panel-body">Home Page!</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </script>

   <script type="text/ng-template" id="Page1.html">
      <div>
         <p>Hello</p>
         <iframe class="browserframe" id='myiframe' src="http://www.google.com" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0">
            </iframe>
      </div>
   </script>

   <div ng-view>
   </div>

</body>

<footer>



</footer>

</html>
```

app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider,$compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist (/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel|chrome-extension):/);
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl : 'main.html',
            controller : "MainController"
        })
        .when("/Page1", {
            templateUrl: 'Page1.html',
            controller: 'Page1Controller'
        })
        .otherwise( {
            templateUrl : 'main.html',
            controller : "MainController"
        })
});

app.controller('MainController', function ($scope){

});

app.controller('Page1Controller', function ($scope){

});

function resizeMenu() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}

function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

Comment: are you sure that local angularjs file is loading fine?

Comment: Note that angular 1.6.x is significantly different from <1.5.x

Comment: @devqon was right, once i found and downloaded version 1.4.8 it started working. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a different version of angular than the google CDN. Once i changed my downloaded angular to 1.4.8 it worked.

Answer (score 1):

To add local angularjs files, you can use `bower`. You can install it globally with `npm` through the following command : `npm install -g bower`.

Then you can create a `bower.json` file :

```
{
    "name": "app-name",
    "authors": [],
    "description": "app description",
    "main": "",
    "license": "MIT",
    "homepage": "",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "^1.4.8",
        "angular-route": "^1.4.8"
    }
}
```

You just have to run `bower install` : it will create a repository `bower_components` with the angularjs local files.

Finally, you change the path in your `index.html` to match the location. If the `bower.json` file is next to the `index.html`, the paths would be :

`bower_components/angular/angular.min.js`

`bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js`